# Implementing the Paper Flip Transition using CSS

Tags: html, css, hover, flip

I was trying to implement the paper flip transition using css, so in order to achieve that the tasks that I needed were:

1. I had to move the div from the current position to the left. I was able to achieve it using translate property.
2. I also had to flip the div. I was able to achieve it using scaleX(-1)
3. Finally I had to flip it in curve.

How can I achieve the final part? Here is a link to [CSSDesk](http://www.cssdesk.com/9e4Sh). I have tried the flip transition using *hover*.

Comment: Hi , .Please take the time to read to see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask, We cannot help you if you do not provide any code, can you please put your code

Comment: I have added the code using the cssdesk the link which I have provided. U can check the link provided in the question under name CSSDesk

Comment: https://codepen.io/saquiboye/pen/RGzrpv?editors=1100

Comment: This question still needs a [mcve] in the question itself.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it's what ou were looking for, but here is a quick example :

```css
/* entire container, keeps perspective */
.flip-container {
 perspective: 1500px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top:100px;
}
 /* flip the pane when hovered */
 .flip-container:hover .flipper, .flip-container.hover .flipper {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
 }

.flip-container, .front, .back {
 width: 320px;
 height: 480px;
}

/* flip speed goes here */
.flipper {
 transition: 0.6s;
 transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform-origin: 100%;
 position: relative;
}

/* hide back of pane during swap */
.front, .back {
 backface-visibility: hidden;

 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
}

/* front pane, placed above back */
.front {
  background-color:red;
 z-index: 2;
 /* for firefox 31 */
 transform: rotateY(0deg);
}

/* back, initially hidden pane */
.back {
  background-color:green;
 transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="flip-container" ontouchstart="this.classList.toggle('hover');">
 <div class="flipper">
  <div class="front">
           <p>FRONT</p>
  </div>
  <div class="back">
           <p>BACK</p>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

The key to acheive 3d effect is `perspective: 1500px;`
This example is based on [this amazing article](https://davidwalsh.name/css-flip) which explain the property

Comment: Thank for the answer I was trying to achieve something like this http://www.turnjs.com/.

Comment: Then you should use this plugin if you want to acheive the same result

Comment: There are many changes I want to make not just the flip so I was trying to develop it using only css.

Comment: I think it's not really possible to do it with only css. Check [this codepen](https://codepen.io/jabaz007/pen/yMjpYP), it use jQuery and another plugin but it seems to be more customizable